# One UIPicker with multiple UITextFields saving selector placement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a view that has 5 `UITextFields` that brings up one instance of a `UIPickerView`. The problem is that the selector indicator wants to always start at the array position that the previous text field left off. For example I have 2 arrays 1 cat, dog, horse and 2house, barn, school. If i select the first text field and select dog, when I click the second text field the indicator view starts at barn. Currently I just have it set to animate to position 0 of each array, but is there a way that I can have them each start at the 0 position in the array and then save the position of each array using the one instance of the UIPicker? Thanks!

edit: sorry, my syntax prevent some of my question from showing

Comment: i dont understand your question clearly ..please give more discription with code :)

Comment: `[yourPicker reloadAllComponents]` try it

Comment: I'm not sure how much code will help, but I will do my best to explain better :) I have multiple textfield that bring up a single instance of a UIPicker. Every time I change arrays I use `[pickr selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];` so that the picker is at the first item I have in my array because if I didn't the picker would select which ever position I previously selected. What I want to do, is if the user clicks back on a previous text field, I want the array item they selected before to be selected not the first item of that array(which happens because of my code above). Better Sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two int iVar for saving indexes of picker while selecting row from picker.

```
int a,b;
BOOL isArray1IsUsedInPicker;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(isArray1IsUsedInPicker)
       a=row;
    else
       b=row;
}
```

and when you reload the picker according to your array, adjust BOOL variable accordingly

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
       // your code ---
        // set  isArray1IsUsedInPicker = YES; if going to use array1 else set NO 

        [picker reloadComponent];

       if(isArray1IsUsedInPicker)
          [picker selectRow:a inComponent:0 animated:NO];
       else
          [picker selectRow:b inComponent:0 animated:NO];

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take one `BOOL` variable For Example...

```
BOOL Array1;
```

set this variable value in `viewDidLoad:` method

```
Array1 = YES;//or set NO which you want...
```

after that in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method just set this `BOOL` variable value true and false and then reload `UIPickerView` like bellow...

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


    if (textField == textField1) {
        Array1 = YES;
    }
    else {
        Array1 = NO;
    }
    [yourPickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

and use this bellow code and just logic from this example..

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    if (Array1) {
        return [array1 count];
    }

    else{
        return [array2 count];
    }

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    if (Array1) {
        return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    else{
        return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    if (Array1) {

        textField1.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row]; 
    }
    else{
        textField2.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:row]; 
    }
}
```